# Maximum acceleration of a falling ball

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

> A ball is released at a height of 2 meters, this ball rebounds and comes back to almost the same height. If the ball is flattened 1 cm when hitting the ground. What is a good estimation in orders of magnitude for the acceleration.

At first thought I would say that In the order of $10\space m/s^2$.Because the force that is acting on the ball is that of gravity and therefore is constant. It seems rather simply but I think there might be a catch is there such catch ?

Comment: What acceleration? There is one acceleration when it's falling, another when hitting the ground (and coming momentarily to rest, before the rebound), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The ball decelerates from its maximum speed, when it touch the ground, to zero in the space of 1 cm. You can use that to compute the acceleration during the collision.

Answer (score 0):

Work done is kinetic energy when hitting ground therefore potential energy at 2m (mgh)

Consider work done to be along 0.01m

Now calculate the force required

Work = Force times Distance

Use F= ma to change into acceleration